# IllegalWriteException when trying to write flags in JavaMail IMAP

Tags: java, swing, email, exception, jakarta-mail

Currently I am trying to set the seen flag on an IMAP email like this:

```
messages[EmailNumber].setFlag(Flag.SEEN, true);
messages[EmailNumber].saveChanges();
```

Where messages[] is an array of Message object populated by loading all the emails in a folder (which is set to have Read/Write access) and EmailNumber is a specific email in the array computed by the user's choice of an Email in a JTable that I am populating with the emails themselves.

However this keeps giving me this on the second line:

```
javax.mail.IllegalWriteException: IMAPMessage is read-only
```

Even though I populate the messages array (in a different function) like this:

```
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
messages = folder.getMessages();
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IMAP messages are read-only, just like POP3 messages. It's a limitation of the
protocol, not JavaMail. The closest you can get to modifying a message is to
read the message, make a local copy using the MimeMessage copy constructor,
modify the copy, append the copy to the folder, and delete the original message.

The javadocs for IMAPMessage were accidentally omitted. But then, it doesn't
have any methods that will help you solve this problem.

Refer : https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1589468

Comment: It seems like you are correct, however, in that case, it seems completely excessive to have to create a completely new MIMEMessage just to mark the email as read. May have to look deeper into this first, to see if there is any way around it.

Answer (score 10):

Remove the call to saveChanges, it's unnecessary here.

Comment: Good hint. One doesn't even need READ_WRITE for marking a message as seen!

Comment: for the record: setting a flag has nothing to do with modifying the message / message headers, that's why saveChanges is not needed.

Comment: If the folder is not opened READ_WRITE, the flag changes won't be persistent, if they're allowed at all.

Comment: I checked with another mail client and the flags were set.

Comment: Which flags?  Can you mark a message as deleted even though the folder is open read-only?

Comment: I only tested the "seen" flag.

Answer (score 6):

Consider using `Folder.setFlags()`. It works even on `IMAPFolder` (no need for `Message.saveChanges()`):

```
...     
IMAPFolder fInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
fInbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

SearchTerm searchTerm = <some searchTerm>
Message[] messages = fInbox.search(searchTerm);
fInbox.setFlags(messages, new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), true);
...
```